# Can I test an x64 version of my application on an x86 machine?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, x86, 64-bit

My laptop is running an x86 version of Windows XP. An application we've developed has problems with people running x64 machines. Is there a way to simulate an x64 machine on an x86 machine?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Install a 32 bit version in a VM. As developer, you should have a nice box with 15 or so gb laying around running a hypervisor for testing purposes ;)

Comment: Is a hypervisor anything different than a Virtual Machine?

Comment: Yes. Like a stove is different from spaghetti. The hypervisor RUNS virtual machines. Use google and look up the word.

Answer (score 2):

No, unfortunately this is not possible.

.Net applications which are compiled with the "AnyCPU" option can run on both x86 and 64 bit systems.  However it's not possible to simulate a 64 bit environment on a 32 bit chip (although the reverse is true with Wow64).